# Git commands only running in home directory

Tags: linux, git, debian, shared-hosting, mediatemple

Hi, I'm getting a strange issue on a shared hosting server.

I'm using git version 2.15.1, on debian 7.11, and no matter what directory I run git commands in, they seem to be stuck running in the home directory. For example, when I run `git init` in `~/domains/foo.com/html` I get the response of `Initialized empty Git repository in /nfs/foo/bar/mnt/foo/users/.home/repo.git/` I need to be able to run git as normal in the current directory my shell is in.

Here's the output of `git config -l`:

```
core.worktree=/nfs/foo/foo/mnt/foo/domains/xxxxx.com/html/wp-content/
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.worktree=/html
```

Unfortunately I don't have root access to this box so I'm a bit limited. What am I missing here? I might resort to using git-ftp for this site but I'd rather not.

Comment: `core.worktree` should not be set at all here.

Comment: the top one I set myself, but I added in an attempt to get this to work. I have the same response without it. The bottom core.worktree I'm unable to change, I can't find a config file with that, and I have no access to /etc/ on this system.

Comment: If you run `git config -l --show-origin`, it should show you where each of the config options is coming from.